# what is the criteria to chose the squad of PSL teams and how this is different from IPL

Tags: cricket

I am a cricket fan but I have little bit confusion that how Pakistani franchises select the players in psl and how Indian franchises select the player basically I want to know that how ipl selection criteria is different from psl selection criteria in draft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These all things are based on your cricket management system. what criteria the player should have depend upon your team cricketing staff. Here is the reference of the site that will help u and make your confusion clear..

http://sportsmaza.com/cricket/pakistan-super-league-psl-vs-ipl-indian-premier-league/